# How do you execute .exe files as administrator or give a run as admin option within a batch file in command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe, runas

**I have a medical program that requires multiple programs within a share from a server to be installed. I made a batch file to grab the programs one by one and install them while adding the share location in windows network then removes the network drive. I also need a copy to clipboard method some how because there is no automation in pasting a directory for images in one of the install programs.

Here is what I have so far....**

KEEP IN MIND EVERY PROGRAM HAS TO BE RUN AS ADMIN NOT JUST ADMIN CMD

```
@echo OFF

    COLOR 2

    echo TURN ON UAC TURN OFF UAC REBOOT THEN PRESS ENTER           
    pause

    net use z: \\SERVER01\mdcs\auto_update\_CSInstaller 

    echo OSDetect will now install
    set PATH=\\SERVER01\mdcs\auto_update\_CSInstaller      
    start OSDetect.exe
    pause

    echo OSDetect install attempt 2
    set PATH=\\SERVER01\mdcs\auto_update\_CSInstaller     
    start OSDetect.exe
    pause


    echo COPY THIS DIRECTORY THEN PRESS ENTER
    echo 
    echo \\Server01\oms\pwimage
    pause

    echo do not restart after wsetup installs

    echo wsetup will now install
    set PATH=\\SERVER01\oms\image\pwimage\WSetupDir
    start wsetup.exe
    pause

    echo Setup-3d-Module will now install
    set PATH=\\SERVER01\oms\image\pwimage\WSetupDir\Tools
    start Setup-3D-Module.exe 
    pause

    net use z: \Delete
```

Comment: If you need to copy something to the clipboard see    Clip /?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use PowerShell or VBScript from Batch to elevate privileges (via [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx)).

Note that the **runas** verb is [undocumented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) (not officially supported).

**PowerShell Method**

```
PowerShell -Command (New-Object -com 'Shell.Application').ShellExecute('program.exe', '', '', 'runas')
```

**VBScript Method**

```
set "VB=%Temp%\Admin.vbs"
> "%VB%" echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
>> "%VB%" echo UAC.ShellExecute "program.exe", "", "", "runas"
if exist "%VB%" "%VB%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try on 'elevate.exe', it is a 3rd party tools, and can be used and distributed freely under MIT licenses.

Just create a launcher script like this:

> elevate yourbatchfile.bat

Then all commands executed will be with administrator. 
You can get that from here: http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/

Comment: no problem =D
I used to write things like that for a company too, feel free just share any question you encountered^^

and, as @RGuggisberg mentioned, you can use
`echo \\Server01\oms\pwimage > clip` to copy the path to clipboard.